# How to get last week number with year?

Tags: python

I want to create a function that gives last week with the year

for example, the current week number is 19, so the function should give the result `2023_W18`. And the weeks should start from Monday to Sunday. So I run the script on Monday, and it will give last week's number.

I found a few examples:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2010, 6, 16).isocalendar()[1]
24
```

but how to get last week's number? Do I need to first subtract 7 days from the current day? It should also support when the year change.

Comment: [_"...where a week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar)

Comment: Close votes are ridiculous. What more details or clarity are required?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) to remove 1 week from a `datetime`.

Then use [`isocalendar()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) to get the week number (on index `1`):

```py
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def getLastWeekNumber(date):
    last = date - relativedelta(weeks=1)
    return last.isocalendar()[1]

# Test today
print(getLastWeekNumber(datetime.datetime.now()))
# 18

# Test 2010, 6, 16
print(getLastWeekNumber(datetime.date(2010, 6, 16)))
# 23
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDPCsIwDMbvfYqAlxZ0rAoiwt5APAkexEO1UYtdO7LMsaefdYooeDCn/Pm@X0iqji8xzPrelVUkBmsY2ZUoThTLoWrY@YzQG3Y3tOjZwEv71RTC4gnOyCtT8xbxum7KA5J8INRSQAqfJlAMUJh8u2WbHHWh1SAk5IbCoM9cHY/GY7CGpNrpvRAj2GACcbSmExW5wPL32scd2TsJsZVKqWTXizdkmut8DPMx6Pl/KPnheNKm6Xl3)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

last_week = today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

last_week_year, last_week_number, _ = last_week.isocalendar()

print(f"Last week number with year: {last_week_year} - Week {last_week_number}")
```